# NAT setup on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, iptables, nat, amazon-vpc

This might sound ridiculous for some, but am trying to setup NAT on lightsail so that I can access my private ec2 instances which are connected using VPC peering.

Suppose if 172.31.x.x is my lightsail private ip and 172.26.x.x is my ec2 private ip, how can I forward all inbound connections and their exact port from lightsail to ec2 and similarly all outbound connections from ec2 to public through lightsail.

Edit: As Tim stated in the comments the point of achieving this is to save bandwidth costs and utilise the EC2 power, a perfect match.
We as students are building a SaaS product which highly relies on real-time data processing, hence we wanted such setup. So it's basically two way connection like you would normally have in EC2.

Comment: What is your motivation for this configuration?

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is important to help us help you, particularly as NAT is for outwards communication not inwards. Please edit your question to provide more information. I know that LightSail bandwidth is relatively cheap compared with EC2 bandwidth, but you'll also be paying VPC peering prices for that traffic.

Comment: I have updated my question, sorry for the late reply. But vpc peering charges within the same availability zone is zero right ? If I am wrong here then it's a total waste. But if vpc peering charges are lesser when compared to normal, that still works.

Comment: @Tim can you look in to this, it would be really appreciated. I have also confirmed with AWS Team that there won't be any charges for data transfer between VPC if they are in the same availability zone and if they communicate through private ip.

Comment: NAT is for internet egress. I don't think you really want NAT, I think you want a reverse proxy for ingress and a proxy server for egress.

Comment: @Tim I was confused with the concepts, a reverse proxy is the right thing which I require as it's two way. Can you help with guides for achieving this as I need this for multiple ports or possibly enable all ports on this and block the un necessary using the Security Group in AWS.

Comment: A reverse proxy is for ingress only. A NAT is to allow outgoing unlimited connections while preventing incoming connections. A standard proxy is for caching content for your servers / users. An internet gateway allows unrestricted access in both directions. If your main aim is to use Lightsail to reduce AWS bandwidth please edit your question to say that. Actually at this point it's probably better to start a whole new question that's clear, simple, and says what you're trying to achieve rather than how you think you might achieve it.

Comment: I have started a new thread here: https://serverfault.com/questions/935390/proxy-setup-between-a-private-and-public

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup an AWS Nat gateway for your VPC and set up the routes for more info see

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html

Comment: I'm afraid this does not really address the specific question being asked.  NAT instances are outbound-only, and not related to Lightsail.

Comment: Am trying to achieve this without using AWS Managed NAT or NAT Instances.