# Proxy setup between a private and public

Tags: networking, iptables, proxy, reverse-proxy, subnet

I have two servers:

- Private Server with IP: 172.16.0.2
- Public Server with 172.16.0.3 (private IP) and x.x.x.x (public IP)

What I want to achieve is:

- Incoming communications to Public IP (x.x.x.x) should be transferred to the private Server (172.16.0.2) on the same exact port and similarly the response should be taken back to the public server (x.x.x.) and then back to the source of request.
- If private server (172.16.0.2) sends a request it should be taken to the public (x.x.x.x) and to the internet and the response should be sent back through the public to private.

I am quite bad with networking and I am trying to achieve this using IP tables but only got the incoming connections to work using NAT. But there should be some better or easier way to achieve both way connection. As far as I can understand this can be achieved using proxy.

Answer (score 0):

A [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) is commonly used to direct requests to the back end servers. Many of these have load balancing functions as well, so you can have multiple back ends.

Neither a NAT nor proxy are needed if one "private" server has a public address, such as with IPv6. Harden the service to be public facing, allow ports to that address through the firewall. This has the disadvantage of putting the private server in a public security zone.  A proxy may still be desired for load balancing and security functions.

Comment: Sorry we want to isolate the private server and restrict it only for private connections.